# Can't compile shared library in Mingw, compiler doesn't see system library

Tags: linker, mingw, libtool

I get this warning trying to compile open source library with MinGW (msys2) in Windows

```
*** Warning: linker path does not have real file for library -lcrypt32.
*** I have the capability to make that library automatically link in when
*** you link to this library.  But I can only do this if you have a
*** shared version of the library, which you do not appear to have
*** because I did check the linker path looking for a file starting
*** with libcrypt32 and none of the candidates passed a file format test
*** using a file magic. Last file checked: C:/msys64/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libcrypt32.a
```

Because of this error I can't compile shared library only static.

File `C:/msys64/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libcrypt32.a` exists and normally links in another libraries under the same environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning message is displayed by `libtool` in case when it cannot find appropriate library candidate for linking. In my case the source of problem is my locale. Installed `libtool` uses output of `objdump` to check if found candidate is import library and expects output in English:

```
    if eval $OBJDUMP -f $1 | $SED -e '10q' 2>/dev/null |
       $EGREP 'file format (pei*-i386(.*architecture: i386)?|pe-arm-wince|pe-x86-64|coff-arm|coff-arm64|coff-i386|coff-x86-64)' >/dev/null; then
```

So setting language to English before making library solved my problem: `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 make`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the open source project you're trying to build has an old `configure` script that generates a `libtool` that doesn't work properly yet for Windows (or Windows 64-bit in case that's what you're building for).

Running `autoreconf` is a possible solution to make sure you have a newer `configure` script. Some sources also include some kind of bootstrap script.

I have seen other cases where building shared libraries (DLLs) fails because linker flag `-Wl,-no-undefined` is missing. This can sometimes be fixed by running:

```
sed -i.bak -e "s/\(allow_undefined=\)yes/\1no/" libtool
```

Comment: Missing `-no-undefined` flag causes error during shared library compilation, not warning

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov The linker will fail without that flag when linking the shared object, but autoconf/make will show a warning and build only the static library